# Mapping Exception when indexing in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I get the following exception when i try to index a document.

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse date field [J], tried both date format [dateOptionalTime], and timestamp number with locale []
```

and that is all correct, but is it possible to ignore the exception and index the rest of the fields?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this can be done without re-indexing by adding the "ignore_malformed" flag to the mapping for the field. Here's what I tried and it worked:

## Create new index with a "date" field

```
POST events 
{
  "mappings" : {
    "dates" : {
      "properties" : {
        "lenient_date" : {
          "type" : "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Try adding an malformed date value

```
PUT events/dates/1
{
  "lenient_date" : "1/32/2014"
}
```

Result: parsing error (as expected)

```
{
   "error": "MapperParsingException[failed to parse [lenient_date]]; nested: MapperParsingException[failed to parse date field [1/32/2014], tried both date format [dateOptionalTime], and timestamp number with locale []]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: \"1/32/2014\" is malformed at \"/32/2014\"]; ",
   "status": 400
}
```

GET events/dates/1
Result: date not found (as expected)

```
{
   "_index": "events",
   "_type": "dates",
   "_id": "1",
   "found": false
}
```

## Change mapping to allow malformed values

```
PUT events/dates/_mapping
{
  "dates" : {
    "properties" : {
      "lenient_date" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "ignore_malformed" : true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Try adding the same bad date

```
PUT events/dates/1
{
  "lenient_date" : "1/32/2014"
}
GET events/dates/1
Result: now works
{
   "_index": "events",
   "_type": "dates",
   "_id": "1",
   "_version": 1,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
      "lenient_date": "1/32/2014"
   }
}
```

## Note:

I'm running ES version 1.3.2. I have not checked how the updated mapping affects sorting and filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you get this exception either because you mapped this field as a date or ElasticSearch dynamically identified this field as a date (the first document you used to create the index had a date value for this field).

You can't ignore this exception and index the other information as the document doesn't match the defined mapping.

There are several cases :

- In fact, you don't have date values in this field : you can fix the mapping to what you really need.
- You have date values in this field, but it's not a valid date according to the elasticsearch date formats : you can add this format to the one used by default (using [dynamic_date_formats](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-root-object-type.html#_dynamic_date_formats)) or define the specific [format](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#mapping-date-format) of this field.
- You have sometimes date values, sometimes string values : if it suits your need, you could set the mapping to string to prevent this exception from occuring. You won't get parsing exceptions as it won't get parsed as a date but it won't be possible to perform a range query on this field for example.

Comment: Hoped i did't had to change the mapping and just make elastic ignore it automaticly when i couldn't parse it. Actualy changed the mapping this morning and reindex.